# mypy - No overload variant of "__setitem__" of "list" matches argument types "int", "datetime" [call-overload]

Tags: python, mypy

I read a csv row from a csv file.
It returns an iterable list.

I need to update index 1 of this list from `str` to `datetime`, so I do the following.

```
csv_row[1] = parse_time_helper_function(csv_row[1])
```

I also have a similar thing for index 2 but it parse a `str` to `Decimal`.

The issue here is with `mypy`, when I run `mypy` on the file it returns those 2 errors.

```
error: No overload variant of "__setitem__" of "list" matches argument types "int", "datetime"  [call-overload]

error: No overload variant of "__setitem__" of "list" matches argument types "int", "Decimal"  [call-overload]
```

Comment: Annotate your `csv_row` as `list[Any]` before changing values. List is a homogeneous collection, you cannot have list items of different type (`mypy`, of course, it does not reflect runtime semantics).

Comment: I tried that but the `mypy` error still remains